# Experimental evidence for wavefunction in wavemechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, wavefunction

what experiments do you know, where the wavefunction of a particle (or better its probability distribution) is investigated? Has the prob. distribution for systems like (spherical) potential well, harmonic oscillator, hydrogen atom ever been measured directly?

Comment: Have a look at http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave nature appearing as a probability density distribution is experimentally very evident in the single-electron-ataa time [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles):

[image: dblslit]

Individual electrons are dots on the screen, and the build up over time gives the probability density distribution that clearly shows interference effects of a wave nature.

There are [experiments with Hydrogen atoms](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901) that accumulate measurements of the [orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) of the atom.

[image: h2orb]

> [Examples of four atomic hydrogen states](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901). The middle column shows the experimental measurements, while the column at right shows the time-dependent Schrödinger equation calculations — and they match up rather nicely.